# Batch weird problem using set /p not accepting a value

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'd like to know if everything is fine since I have the value "H1" not working in this set

```
set /p LL1=
IF "%LL1%" == "1" (
    goto :LL1
) ELSE (
    IF "%LL1%" == "EN" (
        goto :LL1
    ) ELSE (
    goto :LLERR
        IF "%LL1%" == "H1" (
            goto :LLH
        ) ELSE (
            IF "%LL1%" == " " (
                goto :LLERR
            ) ELSE (
                IF "%LL1%" == "" (
                    goto :LLERR
                ) ELSE (
                goto :LLERR
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

1 / EN input works, H1 doesn't and space / void is blocked as intended , I am really lost on this one , got any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the first line clears any value for LL1 I think

Comment: You don't need all of those `ELSE`'s!

Comment: @compo says that because of all your GOTO in the then part

Comment: there is the ** extra characters in there too pretty sure.

Comment: Of course H1 will never work. You have a GOTO before it. I agree with Compo. Simplify the code and get rid of all the ELSE clauses.

Comment: Posted a answer with less useless lines and fixed the goto
note: It is working as intended now thanks you guys : D

Comment: I recommend reading [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)

Answer (score 2):

This is the "standard" way to do it:

```
set /p LL1=

IF "%LL1%" == "1"  goto :LL1
IF "%LL1%" == "EN" goto :LL1
IF "%LL1%" == "H1" goto :LLH
goto :LLERR
```

However, I would do it this way:

```
set /p LL1=

rem Call the given label, hide error message
call :Label-%LL1%  2> NUL
if errorlevel 1 goto :LLERR

echo Subroutine called OK
goto :EOF

:Label-1
:Label-EN
echo This is LL1
exit /B

:Label-H1
echo This is LLH
exit /B
```

Or, better yet, using a `choice` comand instead `set /p`

Answer (score -2):

```
set /p LL1=

IF "%LL1%" == "1" (
    goto :LL1
    IF "%LL1%" == "EN" (
        goto :LL1
        IF "%LL1%" == "H1" (
            goto :LLH
            IF "%LL1%" == " " (
                goto :LLERR
                IF "%LL1%" == "" (
                    goto :LLERR
                ) ELSE (
                goto :LLERR
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Is it any better like this so ?

Comment: You really should consider removing much of the nesting too!